# Retrieve SentEvent Details by RequestID via Rest or FuelSDK

Tags: marketing-cloud, rest-api, api, fuel-sdk

Attempting to filter by requestID using FuelSDK in Ruby. Receive the following error:

> :overall_status=>"Error: The Filter Property 'RequestID' is not a
>   retrievable property."

**I believe retrieving by RequestID is possible via SOAP API but can I do so using the SDK or Rest API?** If not, what would be the simplest way to retrieve a specific send?

Answer (score 0):

There is not a way to retrieve tracking information using the RequestID, however there is a way using SendLogs to accomplish what you are looking to do:

http://help.exacttarget.com/en/technical_library/web_service_guide/technical_articles/retrieving_tracking_results_for_one_to_one_triggered_sends/